# Dealing with NAs and blanks in MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a csv file with 5 columns of data for 100 people, ie 100 rows. The data is numeric.

I have parsed this into a MYSQL table.

Problem: the blanks or NAs in the data this are being recognized as 0s in the MYSQL table.

One solution would be to convert them into nulls. However, I have another script (php) that I use to run searches on the MYSQL table. In this script here are 5 separate forms for each of the 5 columns of data where I can search for the max or min for each column. If I run a search with no maxes or mins then nulls in the MYSQL table are excluded from the search and less than 100 rows are outputted from the search query. But I want all 100 rows to be outputted.

I am sure this is a common issue with this type of data.

Comment: It may be helpful if you could share the structure of the table and the SELECT statements you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix your `where` clause to handle nulls.  It is something like:

```
where (@mincol1 is null or col1 >= @mincol1) and
      (@maxcol1 is null or col1 <= @maxcol1)
```